# Why is connecting an analog servo distorting this PWM-wave?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, pwm, servo, troubleshooting

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to steer an analog servo using a PWM-wave generated by this [circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHFJM.png). I found the circuit design from this [article](https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21800930/pulsewidth-modulator-features-versatile-operating-parameters). It consists of three operational amplifiers and it's duty cycle is varied by changing the **V_in** input.

I've run simulations of the circuit in LTSpice, which produce the expected output. Without any servo connected to the output, I see the same waveform on an oscilloscope when I check the output in real-life. In this case, I power the circuitan with a normal power supply. I have a picture of the transient simulation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li2J6.png): where **V_out** is depicted in the graph.

The issue arises whenever I connect the **V_out** output to the servo PWM input, I can't get a clear reading on the oscilloscope for **V_out** anymore. It's distorted and the servo won't stand still either, it moves erratically. When I power the servo with the same frequency and voltage from a function-generator, it works. In both cases the servo's Power and Ground is hooked up to a normal power supply.

Can anyone explain why connecting the servo is causing this distortion? Is there anything I can do to fix this issue and get a clear reading on the oscilloscope when the servo is connected? This all runs on working power supplies so it's not an issue of sufficient power.

**TLDR:**
Trying to steer an analog servo with a generated PWM-wave. I've generated the PWM-wave with this [circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHFJM.png). It works in a LTSpice simulation as can be seen in [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li2J6.png) where **V_out** is plotted. The circuit also works in real-life when **NOT** connected to the servo's PWM input. The servo itself also works when supplied by a function generator by a PWM-wave with the same properties as the generated one. The issue is that when I connect the generated PWM-wave with the servo input: **V_out** gets distorted and the servo moves erratically.